# delete the rows in r if it is below the value of the last row at the same column

Tags: r

I am beginner in r, and trying to delete all rows, which contain values that are less than the "control" or last row, in each column. For this sample data:

```
        A   B   C   D    E
gene1   14  6   8   16  14
gene2   5   6   10  6   4
gene3   2   4   6   3   4
gene4   26  6   18  39  36
gene5   1   2   3   1   2
gene6   2   1   3   1   1
control 8   5   5   4   11
```

I would like to remove all rows that are less than control (including control) leading to:

```
gene1   14  6   8   16  14
gene4   26  6   18  39  36
```

Thank you in advance!!
(sorry, I do not know how to post the question. Hope you could understand what I mean.)

Answer (score 3):

THere's no way to delete anything from `data.frame`. You can only *subset* a `data.frame`. You may then assign this subset to any variable. First initialize your data.frame:

```
df <- read.table(text = "
        A   B   C   D    E
gene1   14  6   8   16  14
gene2   5   6   10  6   4
gene3   2   4   6   3   4
gene4   26  6   18  39  36
gene5   1   2   3   1   2
gene6   2   1   3   1   1
control 8   5   5   4   11
", header = TRUE)
```

Now, the operation is much easier done on a matrix, and transposed. Then it is as straightforward as it can be:

```
m <- t(as.matrix(df))
df[apply(m > m[,'control'], 2, all),]

#       A B  C  D  E
# gene1 14 6  8 16 14
# gene4 26 6 18 39 36
```

So first you compare all the matrix elements (`m > m[,'control']`) and then you perform `all` (logical AND) operation by rows (sensu `df`, actually it is by columns of the transposed matrix). And finally you subset the `df`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution.

```
coolFun<-function(dat,control_vec){ #alternatively you can remove control_vec from here
    aux<-c()
    for(i in 1:nrow(dat)) # iterate to nrow(dat)-1 only
        if(all(dat[i,]>control_vec)==TRUE) #and change it with dat[nrow(dat),]
            aux<-rbind(aux,dat[i,])
    }
    aux
}
```

Comment: oh oh oh, where's the vectorization? :) Let's make a codegolf competition on this :)

Comment: I know that the fastest *to work* solution should be performed with `data.table`, but considering that op is new to R and probably isn't acquainted with data.tables, more readable code would probably be this.